# Data Corruption during load testing on Netty 3.8.0

Tags: netty

Anyone had similar experiences?
In short, I had create a TCPServer, TCPClient, Encoder and Decoder.

On my Encoder and Decoder, I use a signature byte to detect any data corruption.
If I ran a single TCPClient thread. It always work. But I start to have random error when it increase to 4 threads.

Sample code of TestClient.

public class TestClient {
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TestClient.class);

```
public static TCPClient createTCPClient(int times, String host, int port) {
    TCPClient client =  TCPClient.start(host, port);
    if (client.getFuture().awaitUninterruptibly(5000)) logger.info("wait ok");
    if ( client.getFuture().getChannel().isConnected() ) logger.info("connected");
    return client;

}

public static String createString(int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < size ; i ++)
        sb.append("String createString, client send "+i);
    return sb.toString();
}

static class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    TCPClient client;
    int times;

    ClientThread(TCPClient client, int times) {
        this.client = client;
        this.times = times;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int error = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < times ; i ++) {
            logger.info("send "+i);
            try {
                Request request = new Request(new Header("test",i, (byte) 0), createString(i).getBytes());

                Response response = client.sendRequest( request);
                if ( response.isError() ) error ++;
                logger.info(response.toString());
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                error++;
                logger.error( th.getMessage());

            }
        }
        logger.info("ERROR # "+ error);
    }



}



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] opts = new String[] {"-thread","-times","-host","-port"};
    String[] defaults = new String[] {"2", "10", "localhost", "7120" };
    String[] paras = getOpts( args, opts, defaults);
    int threads = Integer.valueOf(paras[0]);
    int times  = Integer.valueOf( paras[1]);
    String host = paras[2];
    int port = Integer.valueOf( paras[3]);
    for ( int i=0; i < threads; i++ ) {
        logger.info("start thread # "+i);
        TCPClient client = createTCPClient(times, host, port);
        new Thread( new ClientThread(client, times)).start();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be that you have a race-condition in your ChannelDownstreamHandler or ChannelUpstreamHandler implementation.